# How would you call a function that multiplies by -1?

Tags: soft-question

I don't come from a mathematical background so I don't know if there's a name for this (negation? inversion?), but I'd like to know how I could name this function:

> $f(x) = -x$

Comment: Negation seems fine. From a fancier perspective it's also an involution (but there are many other involutions).

Comment: Just because something is common doesn't mean that it necessarily has a formal name.

Comment: Negation, or "the additive inverse unary operator."

Comment: Thanks for the answers. To add more context to the question, I'm working with a dataset that has a numeric column with some rows "negated" and the other rows "untransformed". The reason I'm asking is because I want to add a column indicating this and I want it to be clear and precise in meaning. I'm going with IsNegated so far.

Comment: In some contexts, "reflection" might be a good name. (But in other contexts, not.)